# How change font family in algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmicx

Is there any way to set a specific font family for algortihm environment, especially for the comment that placed inside it?

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? There is an [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) that provides `algorithmic` as an environment, just like the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), so we need to be clear about what you're using.

Answer (score 10):

The [`algorithmicx` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) provides a *hook* `\ALG@beginalgorithmic` which is executed at the beginning of the `algorithmic` environment. By default it's set to `\relax`, which does nothing. However, you can update this to set the font size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}

\makeatletter
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\footnotesize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \not= 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is 0}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you only wish to update the `\Comment`s, then redefine `\algorithmiccomment` to suit your needs. Maybe you'll be interested in:

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[2][\normalsize]{{#1\hfill\(\triangleright\) #2}}
```

which sets the default size to `\normalsize`. It would allow you to do something as ridiculous as this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}

\makeatletter
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\footnotesize}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmiccomment[2][\normalsize]{{#1\hfill\(\triangleright\) #2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \not= 0$}\Comment[\tiny]{We have the answer if $r$ is 0}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment[\Large]{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

While I've adjusted the font *size* in the above examples, you can also adjust the font *family* in a similar way.

---

The [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) also provides an `algorithmic` environment. However, it's far more rigid (less flexible) since it redefines the entire `algorithmic` structure with every call to the environment. As such, environment-specific changes are tedious. Here is an example that adds a possible font change (via `\setalgorithmicfont{<font>}`) and an adjustment to the regular `\COMMENT` (passed to `\algorithmiccomment`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}{\setcounter}{\algorithmicfont\setcounter}{}{}
\providecommand{\algorithmicfont}{}
\providecommand{\setalgorithmicfont}[1]{\renewcommand{\algorithmicfont}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{{\tiny\hfill$\triangleright$ #1}}

\begin{document}

\setalgorithmicfont{\footnotesize}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE $r \gets a \bmod b$
    \WHILE{$r \not= 0$}
      \STATE $a \gets b$
      \STATE $b \gets r$\COMMENT{A comment}
      \STATE $r \gets a \bmod b$
    \ENDWHILE
    \STATE \textbf{return} $b$\COMMENT{The gcd is $b$}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```